# Compiling json schema using fastjsonschema gives TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, schema, fastjson

I am using fastjsonschema for validating json record against its schema. The compile method works fine for simple schemas but While compiling the json schema with references [fastjsonschema](https://horejsek.github.io/python-fastjsonschema/modules/fastjsonschema.html#compile) is getting into error.
TypeError: string indices must be integers. Below are the Code snippet, json schema and the error.

Code to compile the schema #####

```
import fastjsonschema

schema_file = open(schema.json)
schema_str = schema_file.read()
validatation = fastjsonschema.compile(schema_str)
```

Content of schema.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "organization",
    "description": "JSON schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "transactionDetail": {
            "id": "https://example.com/transactionDetail",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "transactionID": {
                    "description": "A number assigned by the calling application to uniquely identify this request.",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "transactionTimestamp": {
                    "description": "The date and time when this request was submitted.",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "transactionID"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "organization": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/organization"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "definitions": {
        "organization": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "identifier": {
                    "description": "identification number.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "minLength": 1,
                    "maxLength": 12
                },
                "countryCode": {
                    "description": "The two-letter country code.",
                    "type": "string",
                    "minLength": 2,
                    "maxLength": 2
                },
                "timestamp": {
                    "description": "The date and time that the record was created.",
                    "type": "string"
                },

                "required": [
                    "identifier",
                    "countryCode"
                ],
                "additionalProperties": false
            }
        }
    }
}

Expected Result: Nothing

Actual Result:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/dnbusr1/z-gda-pad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastjsonschema/__init__.py", line 153, in compile
  resolver, code_generator = _factory(definition, handlers)
  File "/dnbusr1/z-gda-pad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastjsonschema/__init__.py", line 193, in _factory
  resolver = RefResolver.from_schema(definition, handlers=handlers)
  File "/dnbusr1/z-gda-pad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastjsonschema/ref_resolver.py", line 89, in from_schema
  **kwargs
  File "/dnbusr1/z-gda-pad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastjsonschema/ref_resolver.py", line 78, in __init__
  self.walk(schema)
  File "/dnbusr1/z-gda-pad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastjsonschema/ref_resolver.py", line 148, in walk
  elif '$ref' in node and isinstance(node['$ref'], str):
      TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this problem too, and it seems you need to feed the fastjsonschema compile and validate methods with a dict (instead of a str).

One way to do this easily is by using the json module in Python:

```
with open(myschema, 'r') as file:
  schemadict = json.loads(file.read())
  validate = fastjsonschema.compile(schemadict)
```